# Parallelize tasks but preserving input order in output

Tags: java, parallel-processing, threadpool

I have a sub system that looks like this:

```
        [read]          [decode]       [deliver] 
Byte      -->  Undecoded  -->   Decoded   -->  Output queue
stream          message         message
```

The input is a socket/byte stream. The first step is to read a message. The next step is to decode the message (and store the result inside the message object). The last step is to deliver the message.

I would like to parallelize the decoding step, but I must keep the output order the same as the input order. So if message A and B are received and the decoding of message B is faster I have to wait until A is done to deliver it.

I have made a naive initial implementation in Java but my profiling indicates that I lose too much in the handover steps (both from the “stream reader” to the “decoder” and from “decoder” to the output). When running a test program on a 24 core computer (including hyper threading) I get:

- 1100 K msg/s when running a single-thread-implementation.
- 110 K msg/s when running a naive 12-thread-implementation (with a lot of
  queues).

My naive implementation is available at http://pastebin.com/be1JqZy3 It is over 200 lines of code so it will probably only interest those who really want to know how it is possible to make a parallel version 10 times slower than a serial (hint: start look at the class ThreadPoolDecoder).

Does anybody has a pattern/framework to use when performing this kind of problem, where the work is continues (stream based) can be parallelized but has to be sorted upon output?

Comment: I see you create your thread manually. Have you looked into using the ThreadPoolExecutor class? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html

Answer (score 2):

The way I handle this in a program I've written (in C#) is to have a priority queue on the output. Each record has an associated record number that's assigned when it's read. Those numbers start at 0 and increase. When a thread is done processing a record, it adds the record to the priority queue.

A separate output thread has an expected record number that starts at zero. This thread monitors the queue, waiting for the expected record number to be added. When the expected record is added, the thread removes it from the queue, outputs it, increments its expected record number, and tries again.

This works quite well in my application with four threads processing records and one handling the output.

Answer (score 2):

1100 K msg/s is really fast (less than 1 microsecond for a message). This time is comparable to the time of put/get message from/to a queue (0.1...1 micros). So in order to make use of parallelization you have to keep the time of uninterruptable processing significantly more tham 1 microsec (say, 1 millisec). This can be done if you assemble small messages into larger ones. Accumulate 1000 messages in a packet, and handle the packet as a unit of work. Process units in parallel.